# Angular .extend changing object reference

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects:

```
var items = [{id:1,name:'one'},{id:2,name:'two'}];
```

I then select one and make a copy:

```
var item = items[0];
var copy = angular.copy(item);
```

I then change a property:

```
item.name = 'changed';
```

What are the values?

```
console.log(item.name);     // changed
console.log(items[0].name); // changed
```

The array element is the same object reference as the `item`, so the properties are the same.

Now I want to undo the change from the copy:

```
item = angular.extend(copy);
```

What are the values?

```
console.log(item.name);     // one
console.log(items[0].name); // changed
```

By using `.extend`, I thought I was setting the properties on the `item`, and NOT changing the object reference, so I was expecting the array item to still be the same object reference as the `item` and thus to have the same `name` property, i.e. 'one'.

What went wrong?

Comment: naming is pretty confusing can you change `var item` all over

Comment: what end result do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend), it takes two args, `dst` and `src`. It will copy `src` object to `dst`, right? So, in this case, instead of doing following thing,

```
item = angular.extend(copy);
```

What you should be doing is,

```
item = angular.extend(items, copy)[0];
```

Here's code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'one'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'two'
  }];

  var item = items[0];
  
  var copy = angular.copy(item);
  item.name = 'changed';

  console.log(item.name); // changed
  console.log(items[0].name); // changed
  console.log("===================");

  item = angular.extend(items, copy)[0];

  console.log(item.name); // one? (nope!)
  console.log(items[0].name); // changed
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what I'm needing is:

```
Object.assign(item, copy);
```